# Having trouble reading a file with numbers (strings) into a dictionary with integer values

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, set

So I have a `data.txt` file that holds information about a car:

```
CAR|PRICE|RPM

TOYOTA|21,000|3,600

HONDA|19,000|4,000
```

And by passing this data file into the function `createCarDictionary` I was able to create a dictionary that creates the car brand as the key and the values as the remaining information in the txt file stored as lists:

```
dict1 = {}

def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    for line in datafile.splitlines():
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        dict1[key] = [value, value2]
    return dict1

datafile = open('data.txt', 'r').read()

createCarDictionary(datafile)
print(dict1)
```

**Output**:

```
{'HONDA': ['19000', '4000'], 'TOYOTA': ['21000', '3600'], 'CAR': ['PRICE', 'RPM']}
```

I am trying to convert the numbers in the txt file into integer values using the for loop in the function above but I get an error since the header `CAR|PRICE|RPM` is what the *for loop* iterates through the first time crashing my program as the header cannot be converted to an integer anywhere.

How can I convert the RPM and PRICE to integers in my `dict1` using my function above, while avoiding and removing the header from the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***isdigit*** method which checks whether the string consists of digits only

```
dict1 = {}
def check_string_and_get_number(value):
    if value.isdigit():
       return int(value)
    else:
       return value
def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    for line in datafile.splitlines():
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        value = check_string_and_get_number(value)
        value2 = check_string_and_get_number(value2)
        dict1[key] = [value, value2]
    return dict1

datafile = open('data.txt', 'r').read()

createCarDictionary(datafile)
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first line using `next`  after opening the file using `with` statement.

**Ex:**

```
dict1 = {}

def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    with open(datafile) as infile:
        next(infile)  #Skip First Line
        for line in infile:
            line = line.replace(',', '')
            key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
            dict1[key] = [value, value2]
        return dict1

createCarDictionary('data.txt')
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
dict1 = {}

def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    for line in datafile.splitlines():
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        dict1[key] = [int(value), int(value2)]
    return dict1

datafile = open('data.txt', 'r').read()

createCarDictionary(datafile)
print(dict1)
```